# tracking a javascript found in pagesource

Tags: javascript, php, html, debugging, sugarcrm

ive tried everything i cud to figure this out, but i cannot track a piece of javascript in a webpage

so, just to give you some context even though my problem is not related to just this scenario. it depends on a much bigger spectrum.

Anyway, im developing on sugarCRM and im trying to edit the default onclick behavior of a slot in calendar module (you dont need to understand this to help me, so please keep reading). when i click on a slot, a modal dialog window opens that lets me log a meeting or a call.

So i tracked down the javascript behind this. ive used firebug and chrome, and they both give a list of all the JS files that are being used on a given webpage
for example i search for "SUGAR.collection" and firebug tells me its located in a file named "sugar_field_grp.js?v=FVh1Z-v5nA6bYov7-aFFqQ" i can see this piece of code resides in sugar_field_grp.js,
but the code im trying to change resides in "index.php?module=Calendar&action=index&parentTab=Activities", firebug actually tells me this is the file that has the javascript i want to change.

I can also right click view page source and i can see that piece of code inside the script tag. so considering this piece of code doesnt reside in a JS file, i cannot change it, its generated at runtime (i think) but there must be some source, there must be a file thats telling sugarCRM to generate this code

tl;dr how to track down a piece of javascript code that resides on pagesource and theres no JS file specified by firebug or chrome save for index.php (this file doesnt have that javascript either)

i know its been a long post
thanks for reading

Comment: try to search all source files for that generated js

Comment: i searched the code "dialog_create", firebug/chrome debugger found this code inside a file called index.php (which essentially means this code is a part of page source, inside a script tag, i mean theres no file included that contains this code, this code is actually a part of page source)

Comment: I mean the same as slebetman.. use grep or similar tools for searching all files...

Comment: oh i get it now. i shall search for that code and update if anything comes up. thanks

Comment: oh my godddd i found it, it was being generated in a TPL file using a smarty engine. i can change it to my liking now. thanks a lot
i used grepWin 64 bit edition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Learn how to search for strings in files on disk on your machine.

On Linux, MacOS and most unixen the go-to tool for this is [`grep`](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/grep/manual/grep.html). This applies to any programming language you work with. For your case simply `cd` into the directory of your source code and do:

```
grep -r SUGAR.collection .
```

If you're using git as your source control tool then `git grep` is much faster.

On Windows there are various GUI tools you can use to search for text in files. Just google: `grep for windows`.

If you're using an IDE then just your IDE's find-in-files functionality.

Comment: i wrote a little c# console application that searches php and js files in a folder for any string i provide. that application has helped me alot to look where $_REQUEST is being called for example or say, SUGAR.util
but when i search for "dialog_create" the search returns empty

Comment: Don't limit yourself to php and js files. The code could be hiding in html or txt files that someone else's using for templating. Just search all files - yes that includes jpg and gif files as well. It definitely will not be in the jpg files (unless it's been inserted by a virus) but trying to filter out file types is more work than is worth it and may lead you to accidentally filter out the one file that contains what you're searching for. Be lazy - just treat all files as text.

Comment: Actually, having said that, grep is a bit smart in that it stops processing a file that it detects as binary so as to not corrupt the terminal/console by outputting binary data. Most programs just detects the presence of nul (0x00) for detecting binary files.

Comment: im using windows 8, do u know an easy way to search for content inside files in windows? i mean is there something prebuilt that u know of? or will I have to build it myself
btw that helped, u r right i shudnt limit myself to php and js types. thanks

Comment: Google: `grep for windows` - there's even a StackOverflow question in the result.

Comment: oh my godddd i found it, it was being generated in a TPL file using a smarty engine. i can change it to my liking now. thanks a lot i used grepWin 64 bit edition

Answer (score 0):

To track down specific code using Chrome / Webkit go through the following two steps:

**Client:**

**1. Search all static text sources**

- Open the Dev Panel using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>
- Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> for a global search dialog to pop up
- Right next to it you can set pretty printing of the JS code to on: button <kbd>{ }</kbd>
- Enter your search term or terms using regular expressions
- *Optional:* Decide if you need a case insensitive search which has a greater searchspace and takes longer
  Example:

  [image]

**2. Search the dynamic user-DOM contents**

- Go to the Tab 'Elements' hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +  <kbd>F</kbd>.
- Enter your search term (This will also search iframes, svg's etc... within the parent DOM)

**3. Recommended:**

- Cross-reference the results of step 1. and step 2.
- If a given string is present in both the DOM and the static sources, then you can assume that the content is not programmatically created on the client-side.

**Server:**

- Many projects perform a media bundling step prior to content-delivery. They pack web-resources into the main file (e.g. index.php) to save HTTP roundtrips.
  Use [sourcemaps](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/) / and or search the entire codebase for a salient static string or a salient keyword near the static string to locate the original source files.

  **Searching files:**

  Locally, I generally use the rapid index, and heuristic search of JetBrain's IDE's (IDEA, PHPStorm,...) and Sublime. The grep-command tool can definitely not compete here in terms of performance. On Windows I additionally use Totalcommander and its archive/regex finding abilities.

  When quickly looking up code on the server you may use something like:

  `grep -r -C10 --color=always 'keyword1|keyword2' htdocs/ | less -R`

  which will also provide you with line-context. two caveats: you may want to filter out binaries first and symlinks outside the scope will be ignored.

Comment: i tracked down the code i want to change, but how do I know which file houses that code. actually i know how to find the file, chrome or firefox specifically tells u the file like xyz.js
but in my case its telling em index.php, and index.php just contains a 8 or 9 lines of php code, no js

Comment: yes i know this feature. but see. in your pic where it tells u the filename is stub.en.js right? 
the code I wanna track, its says the file is index.php and u can even see that code in page source inside a script tag, theres no js file

Comment: The page-sources are searched as well. If the index.php contains said javascript or search term then it will be listed. In the picture above there is only one file containing the search expression.

Comment: yes according to the search "dialog_create" (which i wana look for) has been found, and its inside index.php, but when i open that file there are just a few lines of php code no javascript or anything im interested in

Comment: by page source i mean rightclick>view page source... not the sources tab in chrome debugger

Comment: @masadwin please reconsider your selected answer. You question wasn't clear at the beginning. 'pages' only exist on the client. Speaking of `files`  or `sourecode` makes clear you are speaking of the server side

Comment: i selected the answer that helped me find that code. i think i made it very clear in my description. i used the work 'tracking' that itself implies that i had access to the server side. i admit i didnt mention the server side but i included php in my description. which answer do u think suited for selected answer?